clip a image from top to bottom instead of from bottom to top
I would like to clip a image from top to bottom instead of from bottom to top. I have multiple images with the same width but different height, I wish my code can handle all images without care about image height.
for example, below code expected to clip the top part of the image, but actually output is clip the bottom part of the image.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\w{500pt}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\w,.25*\w);
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (m) {
      \includegraphics[width=\w]{example-image-a}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}





replace the south anchor with one on the north side of the image
use a rectangle with negative height


\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\w{500pt}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (\w,-.25*\w);
    \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0] (m) {
      \includegraphics[width=\w]{example-image-a}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


